# How to formulate that a factor may influence a variable or the changes in that variable?

Tags: economics

I wonder how to formulate how multiple factors (for instance an announcement of Central Bank A, B and C) may influence a variable. For example, consider the following formula:

$$\Delta I^n_t = f (A_t, B_t, C_t)$$ where $I^n_t$ refers to the interest rate of a security with maturity $n$ at time $t$ and $A_t, B_t, C_t$ refer to announcements of central bank A, B and C on time $t$ respectively.

The above formula indicates that changes in variable $I$ are a function of the announcements of the central banks'. However, how can one introduce this equation? Let me show what my concerns are by the following sentences:

> Changes in $I$ may be due to announcements of Central bank A. However,
>   announcements of central bank B and C may also influence **$I$**

My concern is the last part of the sentence, "influence **$I$**". Should this indeed be: "influence **$I$**" or should it be "influence **$\Delta I$**"? I doubt about this because when the announcements influence $I$ then this should automatically lead to a change in $I$ right?. On the other hand, it is not in line with my equation above. Furthermore, isn't it the case that when some factor influences the changes in some variable, that this variable actually influences the speed of changes in this variable (like a second derivative)?

Comment: Do you work with continuous time or its discretized counterpart ?

Comment: Discrete, so time t, time t+1 etc.

Comment: Sounds like the discussion you quote is being a bit informal, meaning that they should have been consistent in talking about changes or levels, but rather are being informal and hoping the functional notation provides the precision. So vote they meant to say "influence $\Delta I$".